# Storing multiple type lambda functions in one type of variable

Tags: c++, lambda

I have my own `Runnable` class that can store function pointer, member function (maybe lambda) pointer or functor and run it in one way. Here's reduced version of it:

```
template<typename returnType, typename... args>
class Runnable
{
private:
    template<typename rreturnType, typename... aargs>
    struct FuncBase
    {
        virtual returnType run(aargs...) const = 0;
        virtual FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>* clone() const = 0;
        virtual ~FuncBase() { }
    };
    template<typename rreturnType, typename... aargs>
    struct Func : FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>
    {
        rreturnType (*func) (aargs...);
        rreturnType run(aargs... arg) const { return func(arg...); }

        FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>* clone() const { return new Func<rreturnType, args...>(func); }

        Func(rreturnType (*func) (aargs...)) : func(func) { }
    };

    template<typename memberType, typename rreturnType, typename... aargs>
    struct MemberFunc : public FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>
    {
        memberType& owner;
        rreturnType (memberType::*member) (args...);
        rreturnType run(aargs... arg) const { return (owner.*member)(arg...); }

        FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>* clone() const { return new MemberFunc<memberType, rreturnType, aargs...>(owner, member); }

        MemberFunc(memberType& owner, rreturnType (memberType::*member) (aargs...)) : owner(owner), member(member) { }
    };

    template<typename functorType, typename rreturnType, typename... aargs>
    struct FunctorFunc : public FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>
    {
        functorType& owner;
        rreturnType run(aargs... arg) const { return owner(arg...); }

        FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>* clone() const { return new FunctorFunc<functorType, rreturnType, aargs...>(owner); }

        FunctorFunc(functorType& owner) : owner(owner) { }
    };

    FuncBase<returnType, args...>* f;

    Runnable(const Runnable<returnType, args...>& r) = delete;
    Runnable<returnType, args...>& operator=(const Runnable<returnType, args...>& r) = delete;

public:
    Runnable(returnType (*func) (args...)) { f = new Func<returnType, args...>(func); }
    template<typename memberType>
    Runnable(memberType& owner, returnType (memberType::*member) (args...)) { f = new MemberFunc<memberType, returnType, args...>(owner, member); }
    template<typename functorType>
    Runnable(functorType& owner) { f = new FunctorFunc<functorType, returnType, args...>(owner); }
    ~Runnable() { delete f; }
    returnType operator() (args... arg) const { return f->run(arg...); }
};
```

And I want to store in the same way a mutable lambda function

I can store normal lambda, but when I try to store mutable lambda e.g:

```
int fk = 20;
    Runnable<double, double> r([&](double d) mutable -> double { cout << fk; return d; });
    r(1.0);
```

I get followig error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Runnable<double, double>::Runnable(main()::__lambda0)'
     Runnable<double, double> r([&](double d) mutable -> double { cout << fk; return d; });
```

When I remove references from Runnable::FunctorFunc

```
template<typename functorType, typename rreturnType, typename... aargs>
    struct FunctorFunc : public FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>
    {
        functorType owner;
        rreturnType run(aargs... arg) { return owner(arg...); }

        FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>* clone() const { return new FunctorFunc<functorType, rreturnType, aargs...>(owner); }

        FunctorFunc(functorType owner) : owner(owner) { }
    };
```

It's right in mutable lambdas but I get following error from normal lambdas:

```
cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Runnable<double, double>::FunctorFunc<tsf::easing::__lambda0, double, double>'
 Runnable(functorType owner) { f = new FunctorFunc<functorType, returnType, args...>(owner); }
                                 ^

                                                                                 ^
```

The main issue is how I can modify this class to accept lambdas.
Or maybe someone have similar class or other solution for this problem

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you doing this for?  Considering that `std::bind`, `std::function` both exist, and wrap all of what you're trying to do just fine, why are you making this class?  Aren't you duplicating things that "just work" very very well?  If there's something missing, please say so.  See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional

Comment: I didn't know about std::function and I wrote Runnable thinking that there isn' t standard library for doing this kind of stuff. I discovered `std::function` today when I was trying to fix this issue :)

Comment: Also note that `std::function` don't allow to capture member functions so my Runnable isn't so useless

Comment: @kubawal `std::function` can store pointers to member functions; there's an example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). As far as I'm concerned, I thought of your `Runnable` more as a learning exercise, and I think it serves this purpose well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evaluation of a lambda expression results in a prvalue temporary. In your constructor for functor objects

```
template<typename functorType> Runnable(functorType& owner) { /*...*/ }
```

you're trying to bind a non-const lvalue reference to such a temporary. This can't work, and it won't work regardless of whether the lambda is mutable or not.

I'm guessing it appeared to work for a non-mutable lambda because you used one that didn't capture anything; such objects are implicitly convertible to function pointers, so that call actually resolved to the constructor taking a function pointer.

You could declare the constructor to take a forwarding reference instead, but you'll have to actually copy or move the argument into the `owner` member of `FunctorFunc`. That member cannot be a reference, as it could be dangling once the call to the constructor has finished - the argument is a temporary if it's a lambda expression, remember?

Here's a modified `FunctorFunc` that does what I described above:

```
template<typename functorType, typename rreturnType, typename... aargs>
struct FunctorFunc : public FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>
{
    functorType owner;
    rreturnType run(aargs... arg) { return owner(arg...); }

    FuncBase<rreturnType, aargs...>* clone() const { return new FunctorFunc<functorType, rreturnType, aargs...>(owner); }

    FunctorFunc(functorType&& owner_) : owner(std::move(owner_)) {}
    FunctorFunc(const functorType& owner_) : owner(owner_) {}
};
```

And here's the modified constructor:

```
template<typename functorType>
Runnable(functorType&& owner) { f = new FunctorFunc<functorType, returnType, args...>(std::forward<functorType>(owner)); }
```

Pay close attention to all the changes I had to make - they're all essential: where are things declared as references and where they're not, the use of `std::forward` and `std::move`. If something's not clear, ask me. The solution handles both rvalue and lvalue callable objects; rvalues would typically be lambdas, while lvalues may be some other types of callable objects that you construct separately.

Note that I also had to remove the `const` qualifier from the declaration of the `run()` member function. That's where the `mutable` part comes in: the function call operator for a non-mutable lambda is `const`, so it can be called on const functor objects. Once the lambda is declared `mutable`, that's no longer true, so `owner` cannot be const anymore, hence the removal of the qualifier from the function declaration.

And now we're getting to your second problem: you also have to remove the `const` qualifier from the declaration of the `run()` member function in the abstract base class `FuncBase`. Otherwise, you're actually declaring a different function in `FunctorFunc`, not overriding the one from the base. Because of this, `FunctorFunc` remains abstract (it still has a pure virtual function not defined); that's what the error message is trying to tell you.

To avoid running into this problem in the future, use the [`override` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) - it'll give you a clear error message.

---

EDIT: The constructor `Runnable(functorType&& owner)` is too generic, it can even act as a copy / move constructor in some cases. Here's a solution for restricting it using the SFINAE sledgehammer.

Initially, I thought I should restrict `functorType` to only match callable types that accept `args...` and return `returnType` as declared in the template parameters for the current instantiation of `Runnable`. To do that, the template parameters for the constructor should look like this:

```
template<typename functorType, typename = std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same<std::result_of_t<functorType(args...)>, returnType>::value>>
```

Alas, the current instantiation of `Runnable` is also a callable type satisfying that condition, and that's exactly what we want to avoid. So, the solution has to exclude this `Runnable` instantiation as well:

```
template<typename functorType, typename = std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<functorType>>, Runnable>::value &&
    std::is_same<std::result_of_t<functorType(args...)>, returnType>::value>>
```

`Runnable`s with the same template parameters as the current instantiation will fail the first test and `Runnable`s with different template parameters will fail the second one, as will any callable type that doesn't have the correct parameters and return type. Maximum fun with type traits...

The code assumes you're using C++14, otherwise it would be (even) more verbose.

Comment: It compiles. But your solution has very strange symptom: it causes SIGSEGV in strchr() BEFORE calling main(), if I call following (empty) function (this function is from class `template<typename T> class Tween`: `template<typename T>
Tween<T>::Tween(T& obj, const Properties<T>& to, sf::Time duration, Easing ease)
    : obj(obj), to(to), duration(duration), progress(0.0), ease(ease)`. Very strange. I keep debuging.

Comment: And other issue: I can't copy Runnable by value, because it causes `call of overloaded 'Runnable(Runnable<double, double>&)' is ambiguous` error`

Comment: Also note that I didn't change `FunctorFunc` class but created new one, `LambdaFunc` that is `FunctorFunc` after your modifications

Comment: Regarding copying: in the code you've included in the question, you declared `Runnable`'s copy constructor as deleted. This implies you don't want to copy them at all. You'll have to decide...

Comment: Having said that, the ambiguity is probably between the canonical copy constructor and the constructor taking a `functorType`: the declaration of the latter is quite general, `functorType` can also match `Runnable<double, double>`, so if you want to enable copying, you'll have to restrict it somehow, either with SFINAE or some other way.

Comment: Regarding the first problem: I really don't see how that could have anything to do with the code in `Runnable`.

Comment: I've added some code for restricting the constructor taking a `functorType`.

Comment: I was so fixated on the lambda issue, I ignored the fact that `functorType&&` in that constructor is actually a *forwarding reference*, so it has to be handled appropriately (you shouldn't move from it in all cases, as it may not refer to an rvalue). Please read my explanations and code solution again, as I made a few changes to account for that.